# Time to cooling an alluminium plate

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, thermal-conduction

I'm trying to build a cloud chamber using four peltier modules. I would like to estimate the time necessary to cool down (to -20°C) the aluminium plate. From my thermodynamic course I remember that the estimated time is given using the below equation:

$\Delta t=\frac{mC\Delta T}{P}$

Where P is the calorific power, m the mass of aluminium, C the specific heat capacity of aluminium and $\Delta T$ the temperature gap. Now consider that:

$P\simeq 50 W$ per peltier module

$\Delta T\simeq 40 °C$

$m\simeq 90g$

$C=0.88\frac{J}{g°C}$

The estimated value of $\Delta t$ is 15 seconds. This value is extremely low. What is the source of the discrepancy?
Obviously it's all very approximate I don't need the precise value but just an estimate.

Comment: How did you estimate the power during cooling?  Are you familiar with Newton cooling and heating?

Answer (score 2):

The discrepancy between what you observe and what you calculate is due to the thermal conductivity of the aluminum.  The equation you're using assumes perfect thermal conductivity (or rough equivalent).  Your four peltier modules contact surface regions of your aluminum plate and probably rapidly cool that aluminum that is in direct contact, but then the remaining bulk of the aluminum plate is cooled by transfer of heat to the surface regions in contact with the peltier coolers.  The time of that heat transfer is controlled by the thermal conductivity of the aluminum.  Hence the time to cool the plate is a combination of the equation you provide and one governing the thermal conductivity within the aluminum.